# How to find all local minimums of a function efficiently

Tags: random, minimization

This question is related to global optimization and it is simpler. The task is to find all local minimums of a function. This is useful sometimes, for example, in physics we might want to find metastable states besides the true ground state in phase space. I have a naive implementation which has been tested on a scalar function x*sin(x)+x*cos(2*x) by randomly searching points in the interval. But clearly this is not efficient. The code and output are attached if you are interested.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from scipy import *
from numpy import *
from pylab import *
from numpy import random
"""
search all of the local minimums using random search  when the functional form of the target function is known.
"""
def function(x):
    return x*sin(x)+x*cos(2*x)
#   return x**4-3*x**3+2

def derivative(x):
    return sin(x)+x*cos(x)+cos(2*x)-2*x*sin(2*x)
#   return 4.*x**3-9.*x**2

def ploting(xr,yr,mls):
    plot(xr,yr)
    grid()
    for xm in mls:
        axvline(x=xm,c='r')
    savefig("plotf.png")
    show()

def findlocmin(x,Nit,step_def=0.1,err=0.0001,gamma=0.01):
    """
    we use gradient decent method to find local minumum using x as the starting point 
    """
    for i in range(Nit):
        slope=derivative(x)
        step=min(step_def,abs(slope)*gamma)
        x=x-step*slope/abs(slope)
#       print step,x
        if(abs(slope)<err):
           print "Found local minimum using "+str(i)+' iterations'
           break
        if i==Nit-1:
            raise Exception("local min is not found using Nit=",str(Nit),'iterations')
    return x

if __name__=="__main__":
    xleft=-9;xright=9
    xs=linspace(xleft,xright,100)
    ys=array([function(x) for x in xs ])
    minls=[]
    Nrand=100;it=0
    Nit=10000
    while it<Nrand:
          xint=random.uniform(xleft,xright)
          xlocm=findlocmin(xint,Nit)
          print xlocm
          minls.append(xlocm)
          it+=1
#   print minls 
    ploting(xs,ys,minls)`]
```

[image: all local minimums of the tested function]

I'd like to know if there exists better solution to this?

Comment: Any idea or comment ?

Comment: I have implemented the method of particle swarm optimization to find all local minimums.This method is more powerful and efficient in general. One thing to note is that you don't need to know/compute the first derivative of the function, which could be really hard to do for complex problems. Here is the link to the code[link](https://github.com/saunter999/PSO/) if you are interested.

Comment: make a genetic algorithm, use every new solution as a penalty with potential field so that solutions diverge from them but this means every new result is extra penalty calculation and may trap some small intensity solutions never to be found so the penalty should be a bit small compared to them.